# KeyError in searching the list/dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, typeerror, keyerror

Getting stuck with something very simple... Please help me spot the bug.

fileA.py

```
big_dict = {
    "iAmKeyA" : "iAmValueA",
    "iAmKeyB" : "iAmValueB",
    "iAmKeyC" : "iAmValueC",
    "iAmKeyD" : "iAmValueD",
    "iAmKeyE" : "iAmValueE",
    "iAmKeyF" : "iAmValueF"
}

def getValue(keyName):
    return big_dict[keyName]
```

mainFile.py

```
import fileA

otherList = [["iAmKeyB", 123, 456], ["iAmKeyA", 321, 654], ["iAmKeyC", 911, 110]]

for listItem in otherList:
    print(fileA.getValue(listItem[0]))
```

Why do I get `KeyError: iAmKeyB`when I try to print the values of `otherList`? If `big_dict` is a nested dictionary, I would even get `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`.

If I try this without for-loop, it can return its value.

```
print(fileA.getValue("iAmKeyB"))
```

I've checked the types of the return values. They are all strings.

Comment: your code looks fine to me

Comment: It is working for me

Answer (score 0):

It works for me.

```
big_dict = {
    "iAmKeyA" : "iAmValueA",
    "iAmKeyB" : "iAmValueB",
    "iAmKeyC" : "iAmValueC",
    "iAmKeyD" : "iAmValueD",
    "iAmKeyE" : "iAmValueE",
    "iAmKeyF" : "iAmValueF"
}

def getValue(keyName):
    return big_dict[keyName]

otherList = [["iAmKeyB", 123, 456], ["iAmKeyA", 321, 654], ["iAmKeyC", 911, 110]]

for listItem in otherList:
    print(getValue(listItem[0]))
```

Output

```
iAmValueB
iAmValueA
iAmValueC
```

Comment: according to question `big_dict` in a separate file